# TableView inside StackView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistackview

I need to show three different tableViews on the screen. 
I don't know exactly how many cells my tableView is going to have, because they are set through the server.

My hierarchy is following:

```
-View
--ScrollView
---ContentView
----StackView
-----View1
------TableView1
-----View2
------TableView2
-----View3
------TableView3
```

How should I set constrains to expand my each view of stackView depending on tableView height.

[image: current situation]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Also, I recommend not doing this. It's unconventional and not a good user experience to have multiple scrolling elements on the screen at once. Putting each of them in a scrollview exacerbates the problem. I don't see why you need anything more than one tableview with sections.

Comment: @ConnorNeville thanks, I also thought about that, so probably I'll  follow your suggestion.
The question is how to set constrains properly in this specific case?

Comment: I've never attempted anything like this but I suspect it will be horribly difficult to get right and horrible UI. Having a `UITableView` (a sub-class of `UIScrollView`) within a `UIScrollView` screams `UIResponder` issues. Having three and needing to expand / collapse sections of a `UIStackView` means you will need to set a `height constraint` for each of the `UITableView`s which you alter at runtime through three `IBOutlet`s. It should be possible but it's not something I would want to setup in IB and debug. I doubt a comprehensive answer is also possible in StackOverflow's format.

Comment: Table views can support different cells, your case has nothing that would not fit into a single table view. There is nothing special for constraints either.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked extensively in a similar UI structure. All you need to do is remove ContentView from the hierarchy. Work with adding your tableviews as the arranged subviews, you would just have to manage constraints inside the interviews (view1,2,3). This will solve your problem.

```
-View
--ScrollView
----StackView
-----View1
------TableView1
-----View2
------TableView2
-----View3
------TableView3
```

Let me know if you need more help.